# ARM assembly: What is the difference between DCD and .word?

Tags: assembly, arm, gnu-assembler, armasm

Here is an explanation of DCD:

https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dui0473/m/directives-reference/dcd-and-dcdu

To me the usage seems very similar with .word. What is the difference between these two?

Comment: They are for different assemblers. ARM ASM uses `DCD`, GNU assembler uses `.word`.

Comment: assembly language for a specific target varies from assembler to assembler